# Google spreadsheet as web service, how to republish on change?

Tags: web-services, google-apps-script

I want to expose part of a Google spreadsheet as a web service, to be consumed by some other web apps. This is fairly straightforward using Apps Script and the Content Service with the outcome as a JSON object.

However since my spreadsheet is edited from time to time, how do I force a refresh to the published JSON after modifications to the spreadsheet? I suppose what I am asking is equivalent to the to "publish to web" plus "republish on change" options in Google Drive.

Thanks for any advice regarding this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the 'other web apps' make a request to your script, it executes whatever you've written in your `doGet()` or `doPost()`. So, if you are returning a JSON using ContentService, then all you have to do read the spreadsheet in your `doGet` or `doPost` and automatically the latest data from the spreadsheet is return in the JSON.

If your spreadsheet content changes after this, then the next call made by the 'other web app' will have the latest data.